# Does 9th hitter in baseball mean something special?

Tags: baseball

I know the fourth player in the batting order is known as the cleanup hitter, also known as the cleanup spot and in modern baseball is almost always one of **the best hitters** on the team.

At about 1′13″ into the video linked below, the announcer says

> that's a pretty good number nine hitter

Does 9th hitter in baseball mean something special? The link starts at 1′8″.

Answer (score 4):

No. The ninth hitter is usually the worst hitter in the lineup. The announcer was just saying that their worst hitter was “pretty good”.

Comment: I wouldn’t go so far as to say they’re usually the worst hitter anymore; many teams play eighth as their worst. But otherwise agree!